# showmount -e nfs_server_hostname does not show all the available mounts for a client, but why?

Tags: mount, network-shares, nas, redhat-enterprise-linux, nfs

NFS_Server is a DataDomain
Client is RHEL 7.3

I run a below command to show available NFS shared for my client system from NFS_server, however, I do not see all the share available to mount.

```
# showmount -e nfs_server_hostname
/test myclientsIP

# showmount -e nfs_server_IP
/test myclientsIP
```

In my case, I wanted a particular mount which was not showing in the results of above command.

still as DataDomain (which is a NFS_Server, in our case here) person told me to mount a particular share even if you don't see it in the output of showmount command above.

and for my surprise it got mounted, hence I ran above command again and still it was not showing in the list. but when I checked output of below command it was surprising for me.

```
# df -h
.
.
.
NFS_Server_IP:/test_Rep /mnt
```

I want to know the reason why it's happening and is there any other command to list such mount points which are hidden otherwise?

Comment: Seems to be a Data Domain "feature" that others have noted.  See https://community.emc.com/thread/237589 for an example.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes that post is definally related but I still don't have the answer as to, why I see that shared when I do showmount -all but I don't see it when I do showmount -e from client system.

Comment: Please show the contents of `/etc/exports`.

Comment: @harrymc I do not have control over Data Domain (DD) & NFS Shares are exported from DD. hence I don't have those details.